# Telerik: Selection out of range

Tags: exception, telerik, outofrangeexception, telerik-combobox

**I use to get the following exception once in a while. Can anyone help me out with this like what leads to this exception. Looks like a RadComboBox exception. Everything looks fine but still sometimes get this error**

```
Message: Message:
Selection out of range
Parameter name: value
Source:
Telerik.Web.UI
Form:
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24Rbsave&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=JU9vuJLThvbH%2bUCc94qqaitnng8ZRK3Lca%2bQdu3%2buBBplt6sFQvZ8zO7KG%2bmaJHkKFA%2fcqiyNyNBSbj2wrPGxeZdkhSB50gLQYNN3mbfI5JH%2bvODQuBsgFOG0zXfST45pptWWGCBNuYTyeh7SiDRwAkXwScbO%2b7Ce2Nn7pA60cxHNoK7dHfifSNs8WG2un%2fMt42VGm4J0C4DWXBiECImkYcrmGc6I8O%2bJkDIBiwz7xDGlvPfkboH0di3V3hlD1cvQiUMuRBDPiQTw2YJwX0u6ma9djhlsSrdMOTwF64KETgy%2bPfxoznmDLUR4kussJWJMz7e1LkclKjAZ0KMpYCd3Ri4ux0UpnRwg0hQQDDwjpnHtmJtdVu051Gx%2bVgc%2ffE476X8RKdJu9IxGtw81mj%2faucKKhz3BiWedxFYf2jNa7yoYM%2b2M7G0FsgJE58LKd%2bl6BUq21RPA1L5Ib7gDoYj%2bfnspHf28GquByE6Mpw3TLUO4I4rss4ob4iwIyYx1bcH%2b%2bVwHVF%2bFLQW0Cn23ppL9GQYmj5Y2OxCFMwSrgoKG%2fzn%2fcfpeQVL9uOwi9vnt2llraAN6nhWCTw08SokRqNKBZBovK2kP1nsdj5%2bc3SJYdbAQn68bHM6uEsj4jnKP0mLEjvPDaMzN6tNZQa99ZqTCZYd02bfv%2fnZACiMhE7gPVa2ftgnBkTFGehWuK4INsPRLZg0Ee6qN1EG5QzW7CD7wigvNQtgEbe5W9ESn4Kjqm9FCDJ5DhTWF10Yrn4EDSnS9fBjvSzcNXdraYn77cxH63PzgXAqzIXrBbWyI1%2bOr8qC%2f7J7V%2fLIMTs2z8ktHr%2fm5jO08L8c%2bjBpdTwoNvpyIOG%2blt0kWCllgXuOr0gb64oqFBQDjEnTm9yogwLKao6fa3JpO%2bvKsq%2fjOF%2bmrlfDW9u%2b2lqsALb1JoNAbwxw2JI%2b9Y2x84ru8cC37TwQUe%2bLhZ0COjw0BXNTmHLaFY2Z570IXher%2ftvveSXM7lL3mdjhfommQXpByI98IyHEjKAokhC8qmg7%2fy5AgFNgRDbB%2fAhwP3M9qm17AGKVAJdPM1yzjXzJCIbQIaoMRKARcTYEPhXydgKH8r40cIuDbELV%2fehIttNJS5hYuPmFcDmGn%2fQCzOgrKshlQswmT6HyXdX5Kh33%2bXOwYGlOMdLnuND6oJIkgs6APWYcGrHFuNkSBzjna0Nuc9CdKyZJZKwAfCOjjq1Sfss%2bUlJQw6lXlw3MaUd52fdprOCwDw7LAOxUyvt6gwNjVdADnXUxQoDMxUcWoVjx73Sb4%2f5KUeywgtyS7pX6xe1tIaoRLGwglY0kqXno73e06Z3yM0rgLTqiRdVHFzzt%2b2YdV3L2GZ219uG3HwHp2hoYcJ7eF8HkGfjZjyu9X1CI2XkGFl5v53LON4hU%2bw1UsJ0XCivUZ%2bKyRGf6SURrhRaupHslJxf4QiAsfxG%2fFHqNMWUcd7Sm2ectyA%2bMZDhFjTcu6U6U1C5GcStBhUh6loU2lX4fFVjwJqX6A5VjXeoODciyXlj2cmHhOYz7kMTdIOI96phzzrPtxSmsgmJ9pGxdpnOj1bBy2u6E7MyNyVaweLIkaH8LSzXUw40iUx3YCP7XhMgu%2f3hJXOw%2bHd%2bZUXjehDaUCxugGnyfSiYKyf0mnmw3l1OsYXzHmAUiA8iNjuv2yQFchICisRFrqKH5McwKH0QM2jcOGe0PYo%2fh1Ku20dcWRqcdwytlQ26AzcZLrSWstDnv5KHtP4HEV5pxZNDLt9%2f8R7GbU2wEHJNJf8VGyFv61rjOdwn9Eaq59uST6ix%2fwnslWTl9w9nrn710LsYWYL42TCBhAwazQo6aYccEzp4N%2bwK%2flqP1t5oTTHAlZW1uIpMG6XfHh5PPANDP6FTiSpFKMNjkrhBHK3o0BQuzeDDQbC3UyJ%2f6LR4nxVbU1rzBocXmxxvpeYN%2bOrZeu5EMjsbxHgkLer6wmKhHIgk5hjeHseUuS6gaOQjiDllBpDcOr1BolzcDbs5Y9jMnb8LXEGtiZppXorFfmePJeOZGVOzx00RvxE2n1TFxAa8Ew2lJ6cRNBFDODLh4Lgp7NoovlbpmzDjY%2fi7blOoa2H50ldzWxV7yEVHoP7tSSukS0SG1NDfnEGfvBrzsQMkFH6VzKhpt0g8q7fh5Nhg9HVKakasBJJWcTdaQYiU7Zuf430rZm9BUvVb7hd3KPtPVfxEWVHQ4LPr1PIaJ%2bb6JvntOtY1Qsc3WkiUaacDScCSIpsz%2fKgQCZD3V3Kz44KhL9%2f2sevCK3N0au5Hj3zsxqArMuUOY0cjb%2bimEeNpx9LTrfasU7rKIa5bLtrn3bgxKblbDuP4hGthJatqESwYexI%2fM33zdpPS46ydBZtYkRaq%2bNRPY02Z0D12fJJDZnTzmAr%2fNKjh8t%2fQKSSWBsM292suadK34W%2bITggRZese0OVO0RJQnVYEcBi2NQKgDwIa8aoCzZrQw6%2fV3v95gzI5OTKBdBcMqAI1iNTCBvrBHal9YgA531pCVs7YxfJsnIV3ZKPhsj0gUOeHWYf57EljXoo9yibkEOveMUG%2f5kLHmF7qWb2uutYJjSR8EeT%2fS34unC%2f%2f8Vq6AiRnBvZl85i89CCXVw2SzpZv1Ki7S25K1Qe5TghKKhniGEo4jtIaSUPCYU6sOAcYXD7QP3qWb7knmt7Z3awlsNlF2IohHsLB9pN8euIz1TbyDXtq2g%2fyKtdC40H3bEgWKgXKVwBMfWBfqalN7o%2fPDGcxIJkO4oVnX%2bVlaIDUCxXKZvv6bWw%2bYUGexutE474xrXo0zL2be%2fY13t%2bPeg%2b%2fqkVT12j41fS7egIr4d%2f3N9nhPnpV%2fjXSKX%2f3RsAXZ0hW3BZUP4HletsYAmvFsYVfutqbmuGkvRLkVz5yUkLVV9RmY4MLwTH6G8J%2fkGYBGT9H%2bs2FDzshr4xsBDC94B070u5W4PhGfvlWRtfP6325qOkUSjaI2xwanRT94UWbPqz1ms6orJin8FSv25M6aZOP966ODJltWSjahEnPUztpkv8kpoVNnYsrxPpHhWeU7pigLHGzw90qZrdRIzuh1UGSi9ClV0OPsR%2bv%2b3zrjPvCN2GQI2MLwiOZqTbkVZ4rDguEHFBDDlnzzMq0cWZvjmvbxG%2b3ecGLquaMy3q0XMiAH6Iytsb820xzfWomdi8ncNbmKbHvDYq4qXP4seB8urmdAhhEyNPJOPbWACBbJ1YXYDMBe5enzg6JILdjUleC2vSdrJzzMlW53DT6j8PrZV3cPDwdNKwoE92dyqw74PRgPn2zAdQFESoQp5l2gKNu%2b0ZwaxVjCKRAvNiakppu65A9mBX63kyX1jPejzWbLRln1TTLUSqA1W8mfvpE6w86CZv33ST3dLBDWFKY65xoFjQd790I%2bGE8wL%2b7jzVFLR9ib0FVTdNGZG5EeaIVGwGihiA1fj%2b2S8dSUrvy6FfZS0hLwJ7OgNL07619p1TP0S52o4rV7IeEnmUslPKLVqU%2fzPHe6TauQ68otYZF7l9jsW4dNoi8xCZCnY1tdG9AqtDR84lnxmvWTPPlryShD2U0FwL1lPgRsLHjEVILiNIJD%2bVSZ8LXZM%2bZJa3yccvg5tabtOEUrk0i44%2fSFCFEAgKJJCwS6w8v1DimrqcwqgE7WC96UZaoVFipXll6QgUJEfLooVnjAeC3YkbVlOvnbT3N%2bFN44EGqZ9EQIssW0A7iUqEVianz9v9mBZkHqB%2bUr7FlysTMBIf56X28b0U6HKwvVEYYbchzk5iZH4AayI%2bm%2fvmOX3EKvgQ%2bu3guzAs%2fw2k%2bWgD4SBUwLNuUmdxJX5nbrkSw9zsh6kpsMeJxiEoK5u9m%2fSVFpHk622A5a9OhwW9IfxOEePsucla5qR8kuDjABWE4vtBsqZ8a2HtPnJS5JlRPhptC7PIYZWhFpehxYqND6tTTrv%2bfLLwPWlRdEo3iE1yCtH%2f4zfCaNLTIyV%2bVrrKgxk0nYRt%2b8fZzfqP4UlCGcBccsJ7ga3C6NQ2%2bNRI0tCxKmSmabMaQO7q1n%2fUxYZASchcqT3aV00Vt9QLieiynGv0UOciHvTLeu06S6u78W3iovBe1AUc0I%2fNQlYi4vXrAMAgWdjUK0rA%2fI8QbRUPi5h%2frw%2b%2fy2nLC4m0ejwOfsSR1GvaGcQPYmzZND3RJOajQS09X6iU0YxlWT3%2frEntOyD30kvv2Jt5vlxW8yBtYSTwXvka%2fubMxPk1Hr8jhmfh1mUS8YQTIq7cQnRWkKnPZ8tf8iZZMD5BQYscBN%2b67exRqB%2brQrB9zIa%2fe7wXepIqbTfrgiRGi92kYBZw7uHhqrYdica%2fwFjGj0al7ZrdFetv4WU4soH7tOD7SOGJzzHX5inOKu5JQH%2fsMnxeonwtj77czwZnt0GMXNJp%2b3sYwqIxlavtDTTZwAuAxt8e1B3Xv2yoVFBHABsaSW2PbSLv9j3s2%2fWJpFF9spM614NqhHLpKU05hQHhcp8LV6cdO4fF4mY4q6OYvBUVMiO9XuErDSFXGXAlUJvAaUjyNElR8BqdAuR4en50V18wQ1cXviL6A11UU5GGnr%2bv6Z07tyRjqWOVFH94vBNiEYP5Ke%2fD%2fzSwG5zVEihzeEwdC7ryi7o0cl9upRP%2bN0rvhsDvEc9v70TJGXTGIGXWW%2b6cIGlCuBogCgRf6XK9uOeXhCyeaQPqzaQ6NmeO3gga%2bTlUm%2bYOpFGhpAixKTvCkXv5mGJ6YssuYa38SCbWN%2fszG6XmYwcY2TiOdnwQizyJBLQ41vrNut3xrmDHdip0hfGqff9xvYaNparaOcXe2fgHBXNDVHtjaOcxMUVef%2bK6VudMPAixFNfD%2bzO7VesCeBg98kT%2fziYj74P2X7SkXNjUBJlMRNJp4lG4zvk7RkBn4qRiXXk4NRbdZNF%2bC%2bIScSlTXyjzs6dy9OJA5UD5yh5rPeiA92M%2bqk7oTl6TJ2q7iW3HXpmkm3pfDajExmRBdYMuy0C62od%2bVXbqvTr%2f4R%2bNiZ82xkJ6MWLm11lW6Q35MEa1p1gKVunpzoyB4Zx9Zii18Qj2c0iGdC63IFjKssaG5L6zrGk%2bqOJptrWQS6ejQnnXFhI%2fgikCTcygFIsy61QJkZJ1EJS7b5XvSxFmEMlIgVUs77JNifEd3arZqpDWpwVygTLtYizNshb2YwgqBSXUtVZRvQQGzFMe6r%2bN5TZ%2fBKm3Tlary1TCnBnGqLue44LRI4j07rnSN3WhnooWXrSKx0zzlei6NfvkHRLJ%2bZdH2kdDm17F1kiSAUTwmNdQ8fnNXonqZTscTqGIH2M1cHZtL5ggxJkzU5qbQcd8sLl85kmkm0LnQX%2blJt1SO9F%2bIt0KlU1d3ixopbPgbQgcjlo5BRvsCSIjlzpInsBjsYSvEyPdOkBmYbM0oCt0DmqQGRh1Q%2b8efiLXpQRX74jCos5cEjsKSPf%2fiqEe8EPnbMPPtBkxfK1BHnw%2fF7sk6FQt2qF9Xp0gqQtWm5Njy4Tps8orcJXqe%2bFgGdQQExm11AOjxX6A4uto0YaGCi%2fW2%2fufDPAXrGPTtxZpUK3L29LGMcrOx8noTc05uyl%2b6tYnuM%2fy1qZBlvT%2f%2fOji4tLr4FwmXnm42c%2fiwRsjTx4b311zlvqTmo0niJdvSxeGWiTl68MGt00My5kNkdoZqR4ZqEVUbEcr4ntBCe8PFyNFLTtIuHM6ulzgT5uq1ys%2b865mckkAteoypxfpIJUdaPLT1hwmPgjx%2fMKKL6LNPvR%2blN8F%2f4v8HDcw3nZ1S1g%2bsEpGopwujx3sdy3NwyAhBQJjIdjb4xyKGYx03vYasQ2ZsawHN08ReI8kyq3Q4cNtq7kXRZMRigQd6TMQvMP3JSk9vF2JTFrnBNIFlUEkt7Hw%2fK7IDQIFzU%2fcB7mUsmC6a624iIn9a4Na4pZLAwHe1LVF2gXwUuk0huud7n97Ain0sU4iTrZHBYB8RpYlMthr79tedUSeJcXh7VCsHCIir8AmifreiyQInVWU795wyg08vEB5qeeQ0b0fw5ZeuAUR%2f6u9x8nZrPIW0dyoIeydb86EOwAdH2hKthik7d%2fxURYPQsZblXy2bGz0jXRxKHpO8uCgJTWvyXv6QOkRnlVV%2fHntj9Xk16HJ3HEGz8xuSj9OhYa9NofwTTISL3aD2cBMd%2bQEN8DHbTdRGcYk8MBWf4I76HH8Fnj%2bUPqbAk%2fYd%2fHBJBva8nV3FOieW56kPizgpwG2JkhuS1lTv2Okr9XHr1RWdd5j6394pZ84oRNE34G9D1AwEfv4NuyH0v8nsfUAg0Rchl7V7utm%2b8MXTG5RjGQwW4qofuqXv3i5JWtyjKWbVjr60gz%2bi%2bQqso3nznbx1ttlT9iXYRAljLRbKpA%2bfxsWjMoftyKFxe60mPVpova%2fUX3rEfBF1ftuWCLJukAQv8PgJosXpmK8AIQLivfJafKWXH827%2fwSvs0W5e5J02LPEk2EVJBkEHQ9uwwKHKfN9QHbaJY6zCWFFREMDwKyCJT0R83qwlDcnIu8gLxLOGJ4R0bbNMW6cs47HteRqU5WLtYE48pDD%2bSZgKuVQkpPmCMC2KbHQiENRE3bdxtYERc2N0lVZGOq6Fb7q%2fOTABu7VfeTW0744ENz9PslZYpcNwKRdE%2bLj9euXUnP4I8USA8XS68Ylq%2fCGT3gSt6Bp3g6V6yG40VK5o4MTZZEOoe9c%2fgt2utY6dpIswy6Mfn7TPMlAMxBDa041K4W4Vma8GjuEpHr08HYCugMOVCbAgsoN%2fRtu%2b0TDJPocPYMwCpbLLg7rZbijX7omeyJXURZakZMALIv1%2fHTffCQukwYkrzPvh6n4maIdZUOEP%2borjmAGRI%2bJgJqWoRLItEM6Td1ppFHqyCa72NPt9S0%2ftc%2bPsxA2LyTYAi%2bq23oxqIOj188sAlHXOzTdIl%2fVmaeDujw3XDHd%2f7EnmOGfjyu1WsIXyJ9Gk7v8Pz17tc8KHIf7jccY1elsokUCGCpIjnSZsNqS77adW3Szq%2byA9b1PPD2XljtpKA2XwwO138R6hf8GtxIRpTjJkheanHznd5Xmi1gp5cIQPvOgbkSaQjZqMdCF3Xt5uKPyKe2wZlwc%2ftLWUemM8wHTCh8%2b2%2b1HiX%2b8PsgiHdxsAlyocGGjy5ZvrBkDdDcF3i0ekpYBc0fAH0aNL28LgWcoCv6mZ3jU%2fkJ%2f3BF1jV2FtASsLTReVz3ec%2b4R5NblPN6GSaqIsX9T2FzRHRtJASzjQkk6M9Aghv9d2YBek0Bb2RR1VA6WyG%2fWbgJLdC3JAavVxQcJBoFbeSa2Dz8hwdSGeEary3AdyVGJQApMoFT7akYW2F4uNXd0BD%2f7P5p%2fqBOZy%2b8w6GILewkOt5VgJhVX2LWKVZFPW3k0x7I2APioXEVsAPsk41caa1jixiabT6RLNAUBbSY9a%2bbafd1qkQtNAjqYPLDIlvcwFqQwsRq%2fDRdxftGME73dOgbtDIaWXBhFPOU%2frRcI1zNwXvZaTCBXYh1iF%2fds9ImVm336cLtQtpihzkkMFRwUtgPhKDCyAWFjnFHuIZwUXoUV4Q7OxyaliEqrSlRYoOu%2bKjxa%2bgeLk6gHBMyMi%2fD8BpYGsO82NbQO3%2fyGPaGfcyaQrMBrJsOi0FWzpF%2bEtGYavNbrYBqhgA%2fbLgq1XdSWPhA4tOVamDvG0IP4EfEbgKjZMaaDpYZVP2rw81J1Rn9DFJc4dkaTaBYvWjyKNa8Wm5PzW1PZM2EK%2fdJMnx4ZplSTq%2bebP7UkPP6T0LTK8b%2bIcaLH%2b92FZapgLVqqSvfDwT205j6woozbIN6pe9wLNN29DKsJLBYqd3eCCYqLRvbrSmqicf0v8ORiViYynWDU12ayjUoc%2bdusJmALBy0zgRYo7zOiVBxLu%2bu83YSIrWhby7nMo4kCW4k1I7fiO5ndZgPTFsFcxBK122Hp9znBv5vCkRuoJaZL5Mv3W0PT50obs0AvGscHkrLGtbnY1STPxSoGTV7As0yOD%2b205HWGntGNXthV5oq7xXGguXrYIQjHhL2pjL7OzCbpjy78iC3mowDfHlzVH%2fhYiYJFVgZo7fPfhL5rHybbvmgoCGZyzM1nxLNZ7m5BUpfV0%2fz%2fxm37IazbK6no0OtwkieAK8lGZzXHYRVcrqLv0nVh8gZN9qYvJBbuqql%2ftnTVHhlr%2fgsLzycBwR3cA3sT5ICdOg57Q9eR1%2fn5e0%2b0n9Rtc2nRGK4B2hTHwBy3hhrsfYIrp1laCNPYNBTReyN1oI6L9jcuQqDzn%2bJVOIQRfIPjA0JmQWPgLa9n%2f2RLnQwKGVI8C%2ficrChWKcW7b3ydtMmz15I28zDsdUbLJZ%2fjEEbv1iuf6B0kVE6TsNj5ttS0gEH9tR4F1VmR54cI5PrL%2bmMI3ZTLl998B%2b4Zbx7WJRathWKdNZsoOSvdOfkugzrNg7TtXt16suy8HEfd0bY7s1w9t0zoG%2biLBTal%2b6XOvrhJWXrh32%2bpjFEBhc5Acv%2b8t39Ar6xvSOmVlhthNhFUxu6nNTFFcPEbCV2CeCZ98S3JxTzfvSsnEsDQsGJxIZn6d%2fjpSlcuHSSqss%2fr%2f%2buU1QYIUeA7naIJfkKrLfu8VMB9IDXQ%2fj7Kew214Q2sAJltvh5oX%2be9T40Rz6WSqALhrKloGmc3V4xJPmo9iHkZs8oK5%2fDNlv3sy%2fM3w3KFq%2bciiDSrHfAwa4K1rB9XH%2f2IZHee7SRDIZzL7N%2bOnJgKhIn11ZR9EB%2bwrhK0718sLQVKBSmVVvDkfvMI4k8IXY401JS%2bS&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=8E1985B6&ctl00_LoginWindow_ClientState=&Element+To+Be+Copied=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24HfIsPostToCalendar=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24HfIsSignOffRequired=True&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RcOtherOrdersTypes=Provider+Orders&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RcOtherOrdersTypes_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RcbOtherOrdersSubTypes=BLOOD+SUGAR+QID&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RcbOtherOrdersSubTypes_ClientState=%7b%22logEntries%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22value%22%3a%22829%22%2c%22text%22%3a%22BLOOD+SUGAR+QID%22%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22checkedIndices%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22checkedItemsTextOverflows%22%3afalse%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RcbFrequency=Custom+Recurrence&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RcbFrequency_ClientState=%7b%22logEntries%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22value%22%3a%22-2%22%2c%22text%22%3a%22Custom+Recurrence%22%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22checkedIndices%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22checkedItemsTextOverflows%22%3afalse%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24Instruction=0400+-+NPH+42+Units++-+and+REG+21Units+-+%0d%0a1100+-+%0d%0a1600+-++NPH+21+Units+-+and+REG+21+Units+-%0d%0a2100+-+%0d%0aSS+QAC+and+NOT+QHS%0d%0a&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24hfComments=0400+-+NPH+Units+-+and+REG+Units+-+%0d%0a1100+-+%0d%0a1600+-++NPH+Units+-+and+REG+Units+-%0d%0a2100+-+%0d%0aSS+QAC+and+NOT+QHS%0d%0a&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24HfCommentRequiredStatus=false&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RcbOtherOrderStatues=Verbal&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RcbOtherOrderStatues_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RtbNmo=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RtbNmo_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3afalse%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%22%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%22%22%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%22%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24OrderedByUsers=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_OrderedByUsers_ClientState=%7b%22logEntries%22%3anull%2c%22value%22%3a%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000007%22%2c%22text%22%3a%22%22%2c%22enabled%22%3afalse%2c%22checkedIndices%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22checkedItemsTextOverflows%22%3afalse%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24ScheduledDeliveryDateTime=2021-07-10-12-00-00&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24ScheduledDeliveryDateTime%24dateInput=07%2f10%2f2021+12%3a00&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_ScheduledDeliveryDateTime_dateInput_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%222021-07-10-12-00-00%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%222021-07-10-12-00-00%22%2c%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%2207%2f10%2f2021+12%3a00%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_ScheduledDeliveryDateTime_calendar_SD=%5b%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_ScheduledDeliveryDateTime_calendar_AD=%5b%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%2c%5b2099%2c12%2c30%5d%2c%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_ScheduledDeliveryDateTime_timeView_ClientState=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_ScheduledDeliveryDateTime_ClientState=%7b%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RbAdd_ClientState=%7b%22text%22%3a%22Add%22%2c%22value%22%3a%22%22%2c%22checked%22%3afalse%2c%22target%22%3a%22%22%2c%22navigateUrl%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandName%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandArgument%22%3a%22%22%2c%22autoPostBack%22%3atrue%2c%22selectedToggleStateIndex%22%3a0%2c%22validationGroup%22%3anull%2c%22readOnly%22%3afalse%2c%22primary%22%3afalse%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RlbOtherOrderSchedule_ClientState=%7b%22isEnabled%22%3atrue%2c%22logEntries%22%3a%5b%7b%22Type%22%3a3%7d%5d%2c%22selectedIndices%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22checkedIndices%22%3a%5b%5d%2c%22scrollPosition%22%3a0%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RdpRecurrenceStartDate=2021-07-10-11-14-00&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RdpRecurrenceStartDate%24dateInput=07%2f10%2f2021+11%3a14&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceStartDate_dateInput_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%222021-07-10-11-14-00%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%222021-07-10-11-14-00%22%2c%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%2207%2f10%2f2021+11%3a14%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceStartDate_calendar_SD=%5b%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceStartDate_calendar_AD=%5b%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%2c%5b2099%2c12%2c30%5d%2c%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceStartDate_timeView_ClientState=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceStartDate_ClientState=%7b%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RdpRecurrenceEndDate=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RdpRecurrenceEndDate%24dateInput=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceEndDate_dateInput_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%22%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%22%22%2c%22minDateStr%22%3a%221980-01-01-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%22%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceEndDate_calendar_SD=%5b%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceEndDate_calendar_AD=%5b%5b1980%2c1%2c1%5d%2c%5b2099%2c12%2c30%5d%2c%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceEndDate_timeView_ClientState=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RdpRecurrenceEndDate_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24rdpstartdate=2021-07-10-16-00-00&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24rdpstartdate%24dateInput=07%2f10%2f2021+16%3a00&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_rdpstartdate_dateInput_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%222021-07-10-16-00-00%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%222021-07-10-16-00-00%22%2c%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%2207%2f10%2f2021+16%3a00%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_rdpstartdate_calendar_SD=%5b%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_rdpstartdate_calendar_AD=%5b%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%2c%5b2099%2c12%2c30%5d%2c%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_rdpstartdate_timeView_ClientState=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_rdpstartdate_ClientState=%7b%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24RecurrentAppointment=on&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24RepeatFrequency=RepeatFrequencyDaily&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24HourlyRepeatInterval=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_HourlyRepeatInterval_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24DailyRecurrenceDetailRadioGroup=RepeatEveryNthDay&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24DailyRepeatInterval=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_DailyRepeatInterval_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24WeeklyRepeatInterval=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_WeeklyRepeatInterval_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24WeeklyWeekDaySaturday=on&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24MonthlyRecurrenceRadioGroup=RepeatEveryNthMonthOnDate&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24MonthlyRepeatDate=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_MonthlyRepeatDate_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a31%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24MonthlyRepeatIntervalForDate=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_MonthlyRepeatIntervalForDate_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24MonthlyDayOrdinalDropDown=first&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_MonthlyDayOrdinalDropDown_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24MonthlyDayMaskDropDown=day&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_MonthlyDayMaskDropDown_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24MonthlyRepeatIntervalForGivenDay=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_MonthlyRepeatIntervalForGivenDay_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyRepeatInterval=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_YearlyRepeatInterval_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyRecurrenceRadioGroup=RepeatEveryYearOnDate&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyRepeatMonthForDate=January&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_YearlyRepeatMonthForDate_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyRepeatDate=1&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_YearlyRepeatDate_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%221%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%221%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a31%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%221%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyDayOrdinalDropDown=first&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_YearlyDayOrdinalDropDown_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyDayMaskDropDown=day&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_YearlyDayMaskDropDown_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24YearlyRepeatMonthForGivenDay=January&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_YearlyRepeatMonthForGivenDay_ClientState=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24RecurrenceRangeRadioGroup=RepeatGivenOccurrences&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24RangeOccurrences=365&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_RangeOccurrences_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%22365%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%22365%22%2c%22minValue%22%3a1%2c%22maxValue%22%3a70368744177664%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%22365%22%7d&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24RangeEndDate=&ctl00%24DefaultContent%24FvOtherOrder%24RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor%24RangeEndDate%24dateInput=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_RangeEndDate_dateInput_ClientState=%7b%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%22emptyMessage%22%3a%22+%22%2c%22validationText%22%3a%22%22%2c%22valueAsString%22%3a%22%22%2c%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%2c%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3a%22+%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_RangeEndDate_ClientState=%7b%22minDateStr%22%3a%222021-07-10-00-00-00%22%2c%22maxDateStr%22%3a%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_SharedCalendar_SD=%5b%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_SharedCalendar_AD=%5b%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%2c%5b2099%2c12%2c30%5d%2c%5b2021%2c7%2c10%5d%5d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor_ClientState=&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_Rbsave_ClientState=%7b%22text%22%3a%22Save+Recurrence%22%2c%22value%22%3a%22%22%2c%22checked%22%3afalse%2c%22target%22%3a%22%22%2c%22navigateUrl%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandName%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandArgument%22%3a%22%22%2c%22autoPostBack%22%3atrue%2c%22selectedToggleStateIndex%22%3a0%2c%22validationGroup%22%3a%22Date%22%2c%22readOnly%22%3afalse%2c%22primary%22%3afalse%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RbClose_ClientState=%7b%22text%22%3a%22Cancel%22%2c%22value%22%3a%22%22%2c%22checked%22%3afalse%2c%22target%22%3a%22%22%2c%22navigateUrl%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandName%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandArgument%22%3a%22%22%2c%22autoPostBack%22%3afalse%2c%22selectedToggleStateIndex%22%3a0%2c%22validationGroup%22%3anull%2c%22readOnly%22%3afalse%2c%22primary%22%3afalse%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RbInsert_ClientState=%7b%22text%22%3a%22Save+Order%22%2c%22value%22%3a%22%22%2c%22checked%22%3afalse%2c%22target%22%3a%22%22%2c%22navigateUrl%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandName%22%3a%22Insert%22%2c%22commandArgument%22%3a%22%22%2c%22autoPostBack%22%3atrue%2c%22selectedToggleStateIndex%22%3a0%2c%22validationGroup%22%3anull%2c%22readOnly%22%3afalse%2c%22primary%22%3afalse%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_FvOtherOrder_RbSaveAndAdd_ClientState=%7b%22text%22%3a%22Save+%26+Add%22%2c%22value%22%3a%22%22%2c%22checked%22%3afalse%2c%22target%22%3a%22%22%2c%22navigateUrl%22%3a%22%22%2c%22commandName%22%3a%22Insert%22%2c%22commandArgument%22%3a%22%22%2c%22autoPostBack%22%3atrue%2c%22selectedToggleStateIndex%22%3a0%2c%22validationGroup%22%3anull%2c%22readOnly%22%3afalse%2c%22primary%22%3afalse%2c%22enabled%22%3atrue%7d&ctl00_DefaultContent_RwOtherOrderDelivery_ClientState=&ctl00_DefaultContent_RwDiscontinue_ClientState=
QUERYSTRING:
Context Message:
TARGETSITE:
Void PerformDataBinding(System.Collections.IEnumerable)
STACKTRACE:
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource)
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformSelect()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.EnsureDataBound()
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
INNEREXCEPTION:

More Information:
Debug Log Information:


Is Postback: True
Browser: Chrome
Version: 91.0
Type: Chrome91
Exception Type: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

HttpContext.Current.IsNull: False
HttpContext.Current.User.IsNull: False
```

Comment: Looks like the value that comes from the client is not in the data source. 8f the request is legitimate check what the dB has. Otherwise, may be an attempt to inject code in inputs that should be expected to throw